# Is there a way to run .exe in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, files

I want to be able to run all of my Steam games on my laptop.  But 2/3 of them are .exe files.  Is there a way to run or convert them as/to .deb files?  Or is there a program that will help me run them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com) for that.  Usually that works well, but not always.  Give [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com) a shot. To install it run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

And there's no way to 'convert' .exe to .deb

Comment: Have you tried wine tool for linux?https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Wine can be very troublesome

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wine tool for linux.
[Wine tool.](https://www.winehq.org/)

It works well with some programs. It works well with some games but depending what games they are I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

Of course but there's no guarantee that it will work you need wine https://www.winehq.org/download/ there must be guides about how to install those games under wine in Linux. Also there's no way to convert those files into Deb.

https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can install virtual box in your Ubuntu PC. Then deploy Windows OS in virtual box. so that you can run exe files in Vbox.
Now new version of vbox has highly interacted with host OS.
Just try this
https://www.virtualbox.org